# torch.cuda.is_available() False even though correct CUDA version and driver are installed

Tags: linux, pytorch

I installed Pytorch 1.5.0 using `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`
nvidia-smi outputs:
`NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00 Driver Version: 440.64.00 CUDA Version: 10.2`

Regarding the information on this [site](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility__table-toolkit-driver) everything should be fine.

However CUDA is still not working, as `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `False`.
Does someone know how I can solve this?

Do I have to reboot the machine?

Comment: Might be worth checking if you have the same problem with Pytorch 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/37336#issuecomment-620353202)

You have to add an additional linker flag at **Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies**

```
-INCLUDE:?warp_size@cuda@at@@YAHXZ
```

Initially I removed this line as it seems weird and `torch.cuda.is_available()` was returning `false` till I insert back this flag and now it works normal.

Comment: I am quite new to this. I read the thread you linked but couldn't understand the similarities to my issue. Could you explain where I have to set this flag. I am working on a linux remote machine.

Comment: @oezguensi Oh I encountered this issue while I'm working with Libtorch 1.5 (C++ version of PyTorch) and then I found your question here. I didn't notice that you are facing this issue with PyTorch (Python) and not Libtorch. My mistake, in that case I might not be able to help you with your issue, Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to be a corrupted driver. Downgrading it and rebooting solved the problem.